# What is the fastest/best way to combine registers with arbitrary lane selections in AVX/SSE?

Tags: intel, sse, intrinsics, avx

Say I have a 128 register holding some floats [x1,x2,x3,x4] and another holding [y1,y2,y3,y4].
What would be the best way, performance wise, to get something like [x1,y1,x2,y2]?

I guess I could shift the registers multiple times, use temporaries, then combine them in multiple steps, but I was wondering if I'm missing some handy instruction that could make my life easier. I figure this is a common thing to do, so I wonder whats the best practice here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case you can do it with one instruction:

```
z = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(x, y);
```

`_mm_unpacklo_xxx`/`_mm_unpackhi_xxx` can be very useful for various data reorganization operations. For the more general cases there are also the `_mm_shuffle_xxx` instructions.

Comment: Oh cool! I'll give that a go later. In general, is this the family of instructions I should check out for arbitrary lane selections? Any other such handy tips?  Thanks!